# Move generated files whilst incrementally renaming them (in ascending order)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, auto-increment, file-rename, movefile

Pictures are generated in a directory, each with the same name. I would like to move them to another directory and rename them in an ascending order using a batch file,

e.g. `bild1.png` -> `1.png`, next time `bild1.png` -> `2.png` and so on.

Currently the generated file overwrites the existing file.

What do I have to write in the batch file so it looks in the new directory and renames it with the next number?

For now, the batch file looks like this:

```
cd C:\stable-diffusion\diffusers\examples\inference

move bild1.png "C:\stable-diffusion\diffusers\examples\inference\Stable Diffusion\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\stable-diffusion\diffusers\examples\inference

SET "destdir=C:\stable-diffusion\diffusers\examples\inference\Stable Diffusion"
SET /a sequence=0
:nextseq
SET /a sequence+=1
IF EXIST "%destdir%\%seqence%.png" goto nextseq

move bild1.png "%destdir%\%seqence%.png"
```

Simply keep incrementing `sequence` until the destination filename does not already exist.